# For a specific theme, how do I build a list of all the possible theme modification names?

Tags: customization, themes, theme-customizer, wp-cli

I'd like to use WP-CLI to modify a theme with `wp theme mod`. But, I do not know what all mods and their associated keys I can set with these commands.

I've found that if I change a specific theme setting via customize.php, then I can use `wp theme mod get --list` to figure out what the key is for the mod and some valid values.

But, mod keys and their valid values seem like the sort of information I should be able to find easily somewhere by looking at code or documentation.

Is there a better way to figure out all of the mod keys for a theme and the valid values for each mod?